# Strange behavior when setting "padding-top" for the content of a "table-cell" div

Tags: css, padding, css-tables

Can someone explain this behavior to me?

take this code:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:960px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; ">
    <div style="background-color:pink;">
        <div style="display:table-cell; padding:10px; width:299px; border-right: solid 1px #f0f0e7; background-color:BlueViolet;">
            <div>TEST#1</div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; padding:10px; width:299px; border-right: solid 1px #f0f0e7; background-color:Purple;">
            <div>TEST#2</div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; padding:10px; width:299px; border:none; background-color:Purple;">
            <div><div style="padding-top:100px; background-color:Yellow;">TEST#3</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the last `<div />` has the ***padding-top***

Although only this one has it, all preceding `<div />` are having the padding.

why is this? Is there a way to prevent padding to being applied to the other divs while being applied to only the concerned div?

Thank you,
René

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how tables work! Every cell in row will always be the same height, just like every cell in a column would be the same width.

If you expect this behaviour but would just like the text to be as high as it can be, add the style

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to the `divs`, as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DfMqy/) shows.

Remember, too, that if you're going to be displaying tabular data, you should just use a regular `table`.

Comment: Wow, you got it.

I understand the height must be the same. But I don't understand why the _padding-top_ being applied to all the cells...

btw, thank you for the jsfiddle link!

Comment: No problem, it's a great resource! If this answers your question, you can click the tick underneath the up/down votes.

Comment: I meant, why are the content of all the other divs being aligned at the bottom when setting _margin-top_ to a one of the div

see this code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DfMqy/1/)

Comment: I would have loved to have you explained... but you gave me a great tip on how to achieve the required result, therefore, I'll give it you answered the question...

Comment: Sorry! I was away. The reason that all the text the at the bottom of the cell is because the default value of `vertical-align` is bottom, so all the text sits as low as it can.